# Notepad++ How to delete carriage return in lines without full stops only

Tags: notepad++

I have documents that contain carriage returns in the middle of sentences, like this:

```
Were there any connections? Or
was all of it
```

I have found a regex for finding these lines (Find: `\w$`) and I can insert a full stop if I want (Replace: `$0.`) but what do I do to insert a space and remove the carriage return/delete it instead so it becomes this:

```
Were there any connections? Or was all of it
```

I have a lot of these to replace so it would be helpful to get a replace command that takes care of all of them.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Replace `(\w)\s*\r?\n` with `$1 ` (extra space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\w)\R(?=\w)`
- Replace with:    A space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\w)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a word character before
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?=\w)      # positive lookbahead, make sure we have a word character after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Seems my earlier comment disappeared. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do it in 2 steps. First `(?<=\w)\R` . Then `\R(?=\w)` .

Comment: @Lod: Doing in two steps is not equivalent. What is your text? May be ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Toto. I had a text file with thousands of those. It found no occurrences with `(?<=\w)\R(?=\w)`. Then I tried with `(?<=\w)\R` and it found roughly half of the occurrences. Then with `\R(?=\w)` and it found the rest.

Comment: @Lod: Probably because you have more than one linebreak between words. Try with the following regex : `(?<=\w)\R+(?=\w)`

Comment: Thanks @Toto. I'll check asa. Be well!